# Add a usercontrol to a treeview

Tags: c#, user-controls, treeview

Im creating a user control, for searching a treeview. 
I would like to add the usercontrol to the top of the treeview. 
I can achieve this by `treeview.controls.add(mycontrol);`

However my user control i placed on top of the tree and hidding parts of the tree. Can I somehow change placement of the tree inside the treeview. Or do i need another approach?

Just to clearify I do not want the usercontrol to be a part of the tree. I only want to display it on the top of the treeview

Comment: Hi Michal. Could you please elaborate a bit

Comment: Will the user control search the node in treeView? If yes, do not add the control in treeView. Just place the control on the page instead.